# Restore 'use default value' for tax class programmatically

Tags: api, tax-class

I want to restore the "*Use Default Value*" option for the **Tax Class** field for all products where the price has store-view scope.

I am testing with the code in the first part of [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8681/set-attributes-to-use-default-value-for-a-list-of-products), however using `setData($attr, false)` doesn't work (nothing happens when I run the code). However, if I change `false` to eg `5` this works and the tax class is updated. I want to restore the "Use default value" option instead of updating the tax class itself.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
$attrArray=array('tax_class_id'); // define array of attributes to set to 'use default value'
$products = array(3253); // ID 3253 = SKU 38356
$stores = array(6);

ini_set("memory_limit","128M");
require_once "../app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
Mage::app();

foreach ($stores as $store_id) {
    foreach ($products as $product_id) {
        foreach ($attrArray as $attr) {
            echo "Restoring '$attr' for product ID#$product_id in store #$store_id...<br />";
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->load($product_id)->setStoreId($store_id)
            ->setData($attr, false)
            ->save();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using `null` in place of `false` as well.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get this to work properly?

I don't want to manipulate the database directly via MySQL for safety reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value to null with:

```
->setData($attr, null)
```

to remove the value on store level and use the default value.

Comment: Unfortunately changing it to `null` doesn't work - same as using `false`, nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove lines from DB, as suggested [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8706/5530).

Basically when you save an attribute value for a website or a store view in a product, Magento adds a line to EAV tables that overrides the default value. So the only way to restore "Use default", is to remove that additional line from DB.

It is a safe procedure, if you know what you are doing. Don't forget to perform a reindex after that.