# Update date attribute for all products

Tags: attributes, product-attribute

For 45.000+ products I want to update a specific date attribute.

I use this custom attribute "new_stock", that all needs the value of "01-01-2000".

How can I easily update this attribute for all these products?

I tried this code, inside a custom .php file and run it by browser. 
But that did not work

```
<?php
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));

foreach($products as $product)
{
$product->setNewStock('2000-01-01');
// below code use for time format 
$product->setNewStockIsFormated(true);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'new_stock');


}?>
```

Comment: Don't use `load()` at the start of your foreach loop. You already have the `$product` that you need, and `$id` is unset anyway, so just remove that whole line. Also try changing `setSpecialFromDateIsFormated` to `setNewStockIsFormated` (though you might not need this line at all, actually).

Comment: @DougMcLean Thanks! But how can I set the correct product ID's for 45,000 products?

Comment: Edited my comment to reflect the edits in your question

Comment: @DougMcLean I edit my code. Should this be correct? And does this run for all products, because I load the code by productIds?

Comment: Also, if you want to apply this to all products, you don't need a `$productIds` array or the `addAttributeToFilter` option. For all products, just use `$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()`

Comment: @DougMcLean So in that case, this should work? See my edit?

Comment: To avoid an over-long comment thread, and for the purposes of readable code, I've supplied an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credit to @VishwasBhatnagar for the code - I'm just clarifying what I believe the finished code should be, to do all products (the to-and-fro in the comments was getting a bit confusing I think).

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require('app/Mage.php'); // this is assuming your script is located in the Magento root dir
Mage::app(); // initiate the Magento engine

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach($products as $product)
{
    $product->setNewStock('2000-01-01');
    // this line might not be required - compare results with & without it 
    $product->setNewStockIsFormated(true);
    $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'new_stock');
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I tried that, but that does not work. That code does also load within 1 sec, so I guess something is wrong.

Comment: Ah yes there are 2 lines that are required at the start of scripts like this, where they exist as a standalone script but still need to use Magento functionality... see my edit above

Comment: Thanks Doug! I also ran exactly that code, but it does the same, complete within 1 sec.

Comment: I think on that occasion it was a bug in my code - I missed out a semicolon, sorry :). I'll edit it to fix that, and I'll also include a couple of lines to make it tell you when errors occur

Comment: @Jelle Share the whole code of your Custom.php in question so that we can point out your error

Comment: Should be OK now. Just out of interest, can you not just use the product grid in the admin panel as @VishwasBhatnagar suggested at the start of his answer?

Comment: @DougMcLean Great it works! But it currently skips some products, do you know why that is? No that is not possible, because we use to many attributes, so that will break the Magento admin.

Comment: Best guess for why it skips some products, is that you have multiple attribute sets and new_stock has not been added to all of them, or perhaps they have a Product Type that the attribute doesn't apply to (Configurable, Downloadable etc)?

Answer (score 3):

In product Grid Select all the desired Products , in action drop down on the right select update attribute

**OR**

you can provide an attribute by below code

```
$product->setAttributeCode($newValue)
$ProductObject->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'attribute_Code');
```

### Example:

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$product->setSpecialFromDate('2010-10-28');
// below code use for time format 
$product->setSpecialFromDateIsFormated(true);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'special_from_date');
```

### Using Product Collection:

```
$productIds = array(1,3,2);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));

foreach($products as $product)
{
    $product->setSpecialFromDate('2010-10-28');
    // below code use for time format 
    $product->setSpecialFromDateIsFormated(true);
    $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'special_from_date');


}
```

Comment: Thanks! But in that case it is the SpecialFromDate attribute. I created a new custom date attribute for this, named "new_stock". How do I need to use your code for that?

Comment: @Jelle Go to catalog>attribute>Manage Attribute > look for your custom attribute and there you can find code

Comment: @Jelle do you know about Magento's magic getter and setter functions? And attribute can be accessed by these functions: change the code from underscore-separated to TitleCase and put the word "get" or "set" before it. So in your case, `$product->setNewStock('2000-01-01');` in place of `$product->setSpecialFromDate('2010-10-28');`. I _think_ it'll also work with `$product->setNewStockIsFormated(true);`, try it out and let us know if not :) Oh and where the above code says `special_from_date` remember to change that to `new_stock` too.

Comment: @DougMcLean Thanks! I edit my question what I tried, but that did not work.

Comment: @Jelle You should be using product collection code , so that you get all the product date and than update the attribute value using the foreach, and i guess you are running a custom script did you included mage.php in that file

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar Thanks! I edit my code, but that does also not work.